# package conflict when installing different flavors signed with different keys

Tags: android, build, signing

When using the same keystore to sign my different flavors on the same device, things are fine. When I use different keys to sign the flavors with different package names (i.e android.padidar.madarsho and android.rooyesh.madarsho) I get the package name conflict error on the device and cannot do so. I have to use a different key for each flavor. What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the keys that have been used to sign the APKs, by default if you are running directly from your IDE and opening your Emulator, the APK installed in the Emulator is signed with your debug-key(usually installed in ~/.android/debug.keystore), so if the previous APK was signed with a different key other than the one you are currently using you will always get the signatures conflict, in order to fix it, make sure you are using the very same key to sign both APKs, even if the previous APK was signed with a debug-key from another SDK, the keys will definitely be different.

Comment: I know about the keys. The package names are different, and i wanna use seperate keys. There should not be a problem right? but there is.